# Vector Application Question (worried im wrong)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

I'm having trouble with this question.

""Three chains attached to a metal ring are being pulled by different people. Christiane is exerting a force
of 1200N at an angle of 30◦
to the horizontal and Hayley is exerting a force of 200N at an angle of 210◦
to the horizontal. What force and in which direction must Benjamin be exerting this force if the ring
does not move? Round your answers to one decimal place"

Answer (score 1):

You have done the problem the right way, but made two crucial arithmetic errors:
$$1200\cos 30^{\circ} - 200 \cos 30^{\circ} = 1000\cos 30^{\circ} = 500\sqrt{3},$$
and similarly for the other set of equations. (You multiplied $\cos 30^{\circ}$ by itself for some reason.)

If you make those changes and rework the problem, you should get an answer of $1000$ N in the direction of $210^{\circ}$.

There is a much easier way to solve this particular problem, though: just recognize that the Christiane and Hailey are pulling in diametrically opposite directions, so all Benjamin needs to do is to pull in the same direction as Hailey with a force that will balance. Of course, that only works in cases like this where the forces relate to each other in some simple way.

Comment: thank you so much! i realized my multiplication of it was wrong!. appreciate it heaps. I figured that much because both vectors were co-linear. I just wasn't sure whether it was 30 degrees from horizontal or 210, but then realized the force wouldn't add up if it was in christines direction, but it would if it was in hayleys. Again, thank you heaps!

Answer (score 1):

Christiane
$$C_x=1200\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}}=600\sqrt{3}N$$
$$C_y=1200\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}=600N$$

Hayley
$$H_x=200\cos{\frac{7\pi}{6}}=-100\sqrt{3}N$$
$$H_x=200\sin{\frac{7\pi}{6}}=-100N$$

Since we want the ring not moving at all, then the sum of vectors in $x$-axis and $y$-axis should be equal to 0
$$B_x=-C_x-H_x=-500\sqrt{3}N$$
$$B_y=-C_y-H_y=-500N$$

Because $\tan{\theta}=\frac{B_y}{B_x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, then $\theta=\frac{7\pi}{6}$

Benjamin should pull the chain with the force of $1000N$ at $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ direction.

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin's application of force must be equal and opposite to the combined force of Christine and Hayley.

$C = (1200 \cos 30^\circ, 1200\sin 30^\circ) = (600\sqrt 3, 600)\\
H = (200\cos 210^\circ, 200\sin 210^\circ) = (-100\sqrt 3, -100)$

Hayley and Christine are pulling in opposite directions!  Ben is pulling in the same direction as Hayley, and pulling with 1000 N force.

If the problem were set up to be a little bit more difficult, we would say.

$H+C = (500\sqrt 3, 500)\\
B + H + C = 0\\
B = -(H+C) = (-500\sqrt 3, -500)$

Magnitude $= \|B\| = \sqrt {(-500\sqrt 3)^2 + (500)^2}$

And the direction is $\text {atan2} \frac{-500}{-500\sqrt 3}$

The atan2 function is similar to the arctan function, except it gives additional directional information when the denominator is negative.

Ben is pulling